# Translate other websites using website translator

Tags: javascript, plugins, web, google-translate, translate

I have an application(preferable) which redirects to an external site. I want to provide an option to user to change to the external site to preferred language from the application or using a browser plugin.

Is it possible to translate any external site to our preferred language?

Answer (score 0):

Then you should consider using [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) to make API calls to the service to translate the external site to your preferred language.

To be more specific, you can [Detect](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language) the language of the external website first, then you can [Translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text) the website and show to your users.